# How destroy the session in index.php?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have an index.php which contains my login form and using a session to login. How do I destroy the session everytime a user access the index.php for security?

Comment: Would you believe [session_destroy()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is this:

```
session_unset();
```

or:

```
session_destroy();
```

depending on your requirement.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php

Comment: but when i put it in the top of my index.php it still doesnt work. I can still access my home.php..I already have this code in my home.php if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_ID'])|| (trim($_SESSION['SESS_ID'])) == ''){ header("location:index.php"); exit(); }

Comment: no. your code is wrong. you mustn't check `if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_ID'])|| (trim($_SESSION['SESS_ID'])) == '')` you must check if the session variable is set.

Comment: if you set your login code as `$_SESSION['login'] = $id;` then you should test it as: `if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])|| (trim($_SESSION['login'])) == '')` and not the way you did. That's why, your interpretation was wrong not my answer..

Comment: or if you wish can you tell me your login variable's name? i mean: `$_SESSION['xyz']` what is `xyz` in your case

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php unset($_SESSION['whatever']); ?>
```

Will remove the session.

Comment: the better way to do it is `session_destroy` or `session_unset`

Comment: How is that better? The session_unset() function frees all session variables currently registered. Here you might only want to clear the user session, which is why I provided a key in the unset parameter.

Comment: but when i put it in the top of my index.php it still doesnt work. I can still access my home.php..I already have this code in my home.php     if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_ID'])|| (trim($_SESSION['SESS_ID'])) == ''){
  header("location:index.php");
  exit();
 }

Comment: its safer if not better.. to do so. because login information is sensitive information

Answer (score 0):

// Completely remove session and associated data:

```
<?php
// open the session.
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// delete the session cookie.
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}
session_unset(); 

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
?>
```